# Leetcode solution complexity - Longest substring without repeating element

Tags: python, time-complexity

I have come up with a solution for the Leetcode probelm "Longest substring without repeating element" that is basically a brute force approach. For practice, I am also trying to find its complexity but would like to get some feedback on how to do it since I am not that great at that.

The solution code

```
class Solution:
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s: str) -> int:
        ## Brute force approach
        if len(s) == 0:
            return 0
        orig_elts = [s[0]]
        pre_length = 1
        idx = 1

        while idx <= len(s) - 1:
            #print("This is idx", idx)
            if s[idx] not in orig_elts:
                orig_elts.append(s[idx])
                pre_length = max(pre_length, len(orig_elts))
                idx += 1
            else:
                pre_length = max(pre_length, len(orig_elts))
                tmp_idx = orig_elts.index(s[idx])
                orig_elts = orig_elts[tmp_idx + 1:]


        return pre_length
```

I believe the complexity is **O(n^2)** since for the while loop I am passing through the whole string once and that has complexity **O(n)** and then the operation of finding if `s[idx]` is in `orig_elts` takes **O(n)**. So I was concluding the algorithm would have **O(n^2)** complexity.

Thanks for any feedback or suggestions on how to calculate this. This kind of question are not my strong suit and so I am trying to get as much practice as possible.

Comment: Yes the complexity is `O(n^2)` that's why using a dictionary (HashMap) instead of an array is much more efficient, you don't have the nested O(n) operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, worst case complexity is `O(n^2)`

Comment: Thanks Kunal! Would you say the way I computed the complexity is a decent analysis?

Comment: @BOlivianoperuano84 I'm not sure what you mean by "decent". Your thought process is correct, and hence and hence the final answer. If you mean, whether your approach is rigorous, it's not, but in most cases, it doesn't need to be. Your intuition should be correct, and you are good.